# SQLAlchemy - Exclusive Resource Distribution

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a module that maintains some kind of exclusive resource (in this case, movie tickets). The model classes are like

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)

class Ticket(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ticket'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column('user_id', ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User)
    seat = Column('seat', String)
```

There may be concurrent requests to buy tickets, but of course each one could be sold to only one user. So I wrote some code like this

```
def acquire_multiple(session, user_id, ticket_id_list):
    session.begin()
    try:
        for tid in ticket_id_list:
            ticket = session.query(Ticket).filter(Ticket.id == tid, Ticket.user_id == None).first()
            if ticket is None:
                raise RuntimeError('ticket sold')
            ticket.user_id = user_id
            session.add(ticket)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
```

Wonder if this could work, or any better plan?

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude, but I just want to share a few **core** coding principles that are absolutely fundamental, which need to be addressed in your code.

Please don't ever raise a RuntimeError. They're runtime for a reason.
Also, if you want to catch an exception, you should catch the actual exception and not write "except:", otherwise you may be catching an exception you didn't intend to handle and may get unexpected results. Also, please never catch an exception you threw in the try block.
Your:

```
if ticket is None:
    raise RuntimeError('ticket sold')
...
except:
    session.rollback()
...
```

can actually be rewritten to:

```
if not ticket:
    session.rollback()
    raise ValueError('ticket sold')
```

which is pythonic and is the correct way to write it. You can actually rewrite that whole for loop to just:

```
if ticket not in ticket_id_list:
    raise ...
```

so then you don't have to iterate through it in python (as opposed to the internal for loop in C). You should also take the

```
ticket = session.query(Ticket).filter(Ticket.id == tid, Ticket.user_id == None).first()
```

out of the for loop, and put it right above it so you're not making extra function calls and adding to the stack if you do keep the for loop.

Now for the actual issue: you would need to associate a lock on the list of tickets taken from threading.Lock() or threading.RLock(). Some aspects of lists can be thread safe, but it's better not to assume. Also a for loop through it is not. You need a lock to ensure that the ticket isn't presented twice and that it's only given to one customer. To be honest as well, from an architecture standpoint, I would make the method return the ticket if it was available or None if it wasn't available, and deal with it the level up, or bubble it all the way up and return it to the view and let it deal with the "ticket sold" message upon getting a NoneType up there.. 
But you could do something like:

```
lock = threading.RLock()

def acquire_multiple(session, user_id, ticket_id_list):
    session.begin()
    with lock:
        try:
            ticket = session.query(Ticket).filter(Ticket.id == tid, Ticket.user_id == None).first()
            try:
                ticket_id_list.remove(ticket)
            except ValueError:
                print("ticket sold")
                session.add(None)
            else:
                session.add(ticket)
        except AttributeError:
            print("No ticket has been selected this session!")
            session.add(None)
        finally:
            session.commit()
```

When you come out of the function, you'll let go of the lock and then someone else can try and pick the ticket and it'll already be sold.

Two try-catch's are absolutely necessary. The first one protects against not having a Ticket in your session, the second is what is considered "pythonic", or "ask for forgiveness, not permission", so we assume it's in the list and handle the possibility it's not in the list. There are certain instances where checking if it's in the list is better (faster performance in looping for one), this is not one of those instances.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. In the real code I raise a custom exception instead of `RuntimeError`. And I use gevent+flask for concurrence, not multi-threaded, so I'm afraid locks won't come in handy.